# Why is this if condition always true (js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, append, conditional-statements

When the first if condition is met, the if condition within it always returns true. I know this, because it appends the same div every time the first if condition is met.  I have limited JS knowledge; it could be something obvious that I'm missing. However, it seems to me that after the second if statement is met and executed, it's condition shouldn't be met again.
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (portfolioImg.attr('src') == 'image.png') 
{
    if (zoomImgHolder.width() != '300px') 
    {
        zoomImgHolder.append('<div id="myContent"></div>');
        zoomImgHolder.css(
        {
            'width' : '300px',
            'height' : '120px'
        });

        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "swfobject/test.swf", 
            "myContent", 
            "300", 
            "120", 
            "9.0.0", 
            "expressInstall.swf");

        zoomImgHolder.vAlign();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#myContent').css(
        {
            'visibilty' : 'visible'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `'visibilty' : 'visible'` has a typo also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As the documentation explains:](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

> The difference between `.css(width)` and `.width()` is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, `400`) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, `400px`).

**`.width()` always returns a number**, and `<any number>` will never equal `300px`.

Answer (score 2):

The width() function in jQuery returns an integer value. Therefore, it could never be equal to the string '300px'.

Just modify your code a bit:

```
if (zoomImgHolder.width() != 300)
```

Answer (score 2):

`.width()` returns a number, not a string:

```
> 300 == '300px'
false
```

Just compare it to `300`:

```
if (zoomImgHolder.width() != 300) {
```